# Trying to understand a derivative question on mathisfun

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to understand this question on mathisfun, here is
[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsFC.png)

However, whilst I understand the solution is $3x^2$ because of the power rule, I don't understand how expanding the brackets of $(x+Δx)^3$ leads to the expansion in the picture, instead I get

$x^3 + 3x^3Δ^2 + 3x^3Δ + 3x^3d^3  - x^3$

which simplifies to

$3x^3Δ2 + 3x^3Δ + 3x^3d^3$

Please help me understand what is going on here, I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: How did you expand the brackets? The formula is $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b +3ab^2 + b^3$.
It occurs to me that you have misunderstood the notation $\Delta x$. It does not mean $\Delta$ times $x$. It is the change in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$(x+\Delta x)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2\Delta x + 3x(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta x )^3$

This is the right expansion. You have mistaken $\Delta x$ for being a multiple of $x$. This is not the case. It represents the change in x. $\Delta $ is not another variable. "$\Delta x$" grouped together is a variable.